# MUI - impossible to override Text type? "Property 'link' does not exist on type 'TypeText'" when using custom theme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, material-ui

I'm trying to add a "link" property to "text" within palette. so that I can do `color: theme.palette.text.link`. [The docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theming/#custom-variables) mentions I need to augment the type, which I'm doing. This **works** for their example of adding the `status.danger` property.

However, when trying to augment the text, this simply doesn't work. i get the following error: `Property 'link' does not exist on type 'TypeText'.`

Is there a different type I need to augment?

THIS WORKS (but it's not what i need):

```
declare module '@mui/material/styles' {
  interface Theme {
    status: {
      danger: string;
    };
  }
  // allow configuration using `createTheme`
  interface ThemeOptions {
    status?: {
      danger?: string;
    };
  }
}
```

THIS DOES NOT WORK:

```
declare module '@mui/material/styles' {
  interface Theme {
    text: {
      link: string;
    };
  }
  // allow configuration using `createTheme`
  interface ThemeOptions {
    text?: {
      link?: string;
    };
  }
}
```

I have also to no avail tried adding:

```
  interface TypeText  {
    text: {
      link: string;
    };
  }
```

[Here's the type](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/01f656bcc40223b002d65c599c6e2a552a154594/packages/mui-material/src/styles/createPalette.d.ts#L13) I'm trying to augment

Comment: Are you getting this error when you create the theme? Also if you want to add a new color to the palette you should take a look [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/palette/#adding-new-colors).

Comment: Not getting any errors when i create the Theme. Also, i dont need to add a color - the danger example was from the docs and was just using it as an example to show that only that works